# Inserting data into mongoose Schema using submit button/input tag

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

So I've been working on a kind of e-commerce website where users can bookmark a shop they liked which then would be saved into the database.

I have two mongoose schemas, one for the shop and another for the user

```
//jshint esversion:6
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate");
const cors = require("cors");


const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// app.use(cors());
// app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.use(session({
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/journalDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const journalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  category: String,
  subcategory: String,
  rating: Number,
  link: String,
  description: String,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  journal: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Journal'}]
});


userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);


const Journal = mongoose.model("Journal", journalSchema);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Each shop has an individual page with a description. And I want to add a button or an input tag, which would save this shop into the user's schema.

Get and Post routes:

```
app.get("/journals/:journalId", function(req, res){
  const requestedJournalId = req.params.journalId;

  Journal.findOne({_id: requestedJournalId}, function(err, foundJournal){
      res.render("stats", {
        _id: foundJournal._id,
        title: foundJournal.title,
        subcategory: foundJournal.subcategory,
        link: foundJournal.link,
        description: foundJournal.description
      });
  });
});

app.post("/stats", function(req, res){
    const favJournal = req.journal.id;
    User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, foundUser) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                foundUser.journal.push(favJournal);
                foundUser.save(function() {
                    res.redirect("/favourite");
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

stats.ejs:

```
<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="flex-container-stats">
        <div class="stats-image">
          <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 350px;max-wdth:500px;"  id="img_DocPreview" src="images/clothes.jfif" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="stats-description">
          <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold "><%=title%></h1>
          <p class="fs-4"><%=subcategory%></p>
          <a href="<%=link%>" target="_blank" ><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="px-2"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a>
          <a href="https://telegram.org/" target="_blank" class="px-2"><i class="fab fa-telegram-plane fa-3x"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
        <form action="/stats" method="post">
          <div class="stats-button">
            <!-- <label for=""><%=_id%></label>
            <input type="submit" name="savedJournal" placeholder="Add to favourite"> -->
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to MongoDB and node.js. Not sure what I'm missing and I wasn't able to find a fitting solution from similar problems I came across.

Answer (score 0):

Change your schemas file to something like the following example:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const journalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    category: String,
    subcategory: String,
    rating: Number,
    link: String,
    description: String,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    journal: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Journal'}]
});

module.exports.userSchema = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
module.exports.journalSchema = mongoose.model('journals', journalSchema);
```

This will then convert your schemas into live models that'll allow your data to actually save inside your database.
Then to require your database use the following example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Journal = require('./path/to/schema-file').journalSchema;
const User = require('./path/to/schema-file').userSchema;

app.get("/journals/:journalId", function(req, res){
  const requestedJournalId = req.params.journalId;

  Journal.findOne({_id: requestedJournalId}, function(err, foundJournal){
      res.render("stats", {
        _id: foundJournal._id,
        title: foundJournal.title,
        subcategory: foundJournal.subcategory,
        link: foundJournal.link,
        description: foundJournal.description
      });
  });
});

app.post("/stats", function(req, res){
    const favJournal = req.journal.id;
    User.findById(req.user.id, function(err, foundUser) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                foundUser.journal.push(favJournal);
                foundUser.save(function() {
                    res.redirect("/favourite");
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already had all of these, forgot to include. Edited the question to avoid further confusion.